# how the TreeBagger handles missing values

Tags: matlab, missing-data, bag

I was wondering if anyone knew how the TreeBagger(Matlab) handles missing values. There seem to be two methods described in literature and by Breiman. One of these (apparently, the better one) uses a recursive/iterative method for computing the missing value.

Does anyone know (for certain) which method is implemented? There are no options available for setting this. I've tried to look through the code, but can't figure out where this is handled and how it is handled.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by missing values. I you mean missing values in the input matrix MatLab seems to ignore them:

From the MatLab 2011a documentation:

> **Supervised Learning (Machine Learning) Workflow and Algorithms**
>
> All supervised learning methods start with an input data matrix,
> usually called X here. Each row of X represents one observation. Each
> column of X represents one variable, or predictor. Represent missing
> entries with NaN values in X. Statistics Toolbox supervised learning
> algorithms can handle NaN values, either by ignoring them or by
> ignoring any row with a NaN value.

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan